# An interesting story about type inference with RxJs and typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, rxjs

I have the following code

```
  let obs$: Observable<string>
   obs$.pipe(
        tap(data => {
          // do stuff
        }),
      );
```

If I use VSCode and hover over `data` variable, I see that this is of type `string` as expected.

Then I add `ingnoreElements` after `tap`

```
obs$.pipe(
    tap(data => {
       // do stuff
    }),
    ignoreElements()
  );
```

Now, if I hover over `data`, type inference tells me that `data` is of type `any`.

This seems like a retroactive inference. Which is the reason behind this type inference behavior?

Here a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-3zaonl) to reproduce this situation.

**THE ANSWER provided by the response from @Andrei Gătej**

The whole mystery lays in the way `ignoreElements()` is declared, i.e.

```
export declare function ignoreElements(): OperatorFunction<any, never>;
```

Now, you place `ignoreElements()` after an operator like `tap()`, which is declared like this

```
export declare function tap<T>(observer: PartialObserver<T>): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T>;
```

and basically within `pipe()` you have a chain such as this

```
MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T>,
OperatorFunction<any, never>
```

which `pipe()` interprets as: *"T" is a generic type, "any" is a real type, then since ignoreElements() expects "any" then "T" must be of type "any"*

And this explains the mystery.

Now there are few possible solutions.
One way is to isolate `ignoreElements()` into a different `pipe()` like this

```
obs$.pipe(
    tap(data => {
       // do stuff
    }),
  )
  .pipe(
    ignoreElements()
  );
```

If you do this the variable `data` is inferred of type `string` which is what we want.

A more elegant solution though would be to change the declaration of `ignoreElements()`. If you declare it like this

```
export declare function ignoreElements<T>(): OperatorFunction<T, never>;
```

everything works as expected without the need of doing any trick.

It may be worth to suggest a change in the declaration of `ignoreElements()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very interesting question!

Let's have a look at `ignoreElements()`'s types:

```js
export function ignoreElements(): OperatorFunction<any, never> {
  return function ignoreElementsOperatorFunction(source: Observable<any>) {
    return source.lift(new IgnoreElementsOperator());
  };
}
```

[*Source*](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/ignoreElements.ts#L38).

The most important thing to notice here is `OperatorFunction`, which is defined as follows:

```js
export interface UnaryFunction<T, R> { (source: T): R; }

export interface OperatorFunction<T, R> extends UnaryFunction<Observable<T>, Observable<R>> {}
```

[*Source*](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/types.ts#L6-L8).

So `UnaryFunction<T, R>` describes a function that receives an **argument** of type `T` and **returns** something of type `R`.

Similarly, `OperatorFunction<T, R>` is a function which accepts an argument which is an `Observable` of type `T` and returns an `Observable` of type `R`.

---

Going back to `ignoreElements()`'s types: `OperatorFunction<any, never>`. So, it means that `ignoreElements` returns a **function** whose argument is an `Observable<any>` and whose return type is `Observable<never>`.

Now let's see the types of `pipe()`:

```js
pipe(): Observable<T>;
pipe<A>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>): Observable<A>;
pipe<A, B>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>): Observable<B>;
pipe<A, B, C>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>): Observable<C>;
```

[*Source*](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Observable.ts#L309-L319).

Every operator returns an `OperationFunction`. For instance, from

```js
pipe<A, B>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>): Observable<B>;
```

we can see that the return type of the first operator is the input type for the second operator and so forth. This is how types are inferred.

Also, `T` can be inferred from the Observable's `constructor`:

```js
constructor(subscribe?: (this: Observable<T>, subscriber: Subscriber<T>) => TeardownLogic) {
  if (subscribe) {
    this._subscribe = subscribe;
  }
}

class Subscriber<T> implements Observer<T> { /* ... */ }

export interface Observer<T> {
  closed?: boolean;
  next: (value: T) => void; // ! 
  error: (err: any) => void;
  complete: () => void;
}
```

[*Source*](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Observable.ts#L38-L42).

Comment: I updated my question with an answer derived from your answer. Thanks.